# Powershell - for loop with multiple conditions

Tags: powershell, for-loop

im trying to have a for loop which ends after 1 of 2 conditions is fullfilled.

I dont know what i am missing but with "-or" between these 2 conditions only one condition seems to be "working" i guess. Should the following for-loop not also quit after the value of $i is 3??

**Here the code:**

```
$test = "test"
$expected = "successful"
for($i = 0; ($i -lt 3) -or ($test -ne $expected); ($i++) -and (sleep 1)){
    if($i -eq 5){
        $test = $expected
    }
    $test
    $i
}
```

**and here is my output:**

test
0
test
1
test
2
test
3
test
4
successful
5

Comment: `-or` makes the loop continue as longer as _either_ condition is satisfied, change the `-or` to an `-and`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should the following for-loop not also quit after the value of `$i` is 3?

Why should it? `($test -ne $expected)` is still `$true`, and you've instructed PowerShell to continue the loop as long as *either* `($i -lt 3)` or `($test -ne $expected)` are true.

Change the loop condition to use the `-and` operator instead:

```
for($i = 0; ($i -lt 3) -and ($test -ne $expected); ($i++) -and (sleep 1))
```

Assuming you want the `sleep 1` statement to execute regardless of the value of `$i`, change the last part to *not* use `-and` too:

```
for($i = 0; ($i -lt 3) -and ($test -ne $expected); ($i++;sleep 1)){
```

Comment: I think it would need `$(..)` for the second example: `$($i++;sleep 1)`